# Centos 4.8 not booting after replacement disk controller

Tags: linux, boot, centos, sata, lvm

I have a quite old Centos 4.8 backup. Root partition is on LVM. (/dev/mapper/centos-root).
This backup (tar.gz archive) works fine if i restore it in Vmware cluster with SCSI controller.

But now i need this backup on real PC with SATA controller.

For now my results are:

- IDE controller - Always reboots after Ext3 FS message
- SATA Controller  - System freeze on message "device-mapper initialised"
- SCSI Controller - System boots normally

So seems to be that the problem with controller.
I've tried to add support for SATA in initrd wih the **mkinitrd** command but with no luck...

How can i boot this system on SATA disk with SATA Controller?
thanks!